# Is there a more clever way of testing if the number 0 is defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the below function,

```
const isDefined = value => !!value
```

If `0` is passed, it'd falsely fail.

So, if I'm mapping something like,

```
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const Component = () => data.map((element, index) => <div key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>{element}</div>

const handleClick = param => console.log(`is ${!param ? 'not' : ''} param!`)
```

Then for index `0`, it would print `is not param!`

I'd fix it with,

```
const handleClick = (param = null) => console.log(`is ${!param === null ? 'not' : ''} param!`)
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more clever way to get around Javascript's falsiness concept, considering `0` is considered falsy?

Comment: You know in advance that the array index will be from 0 to N. Why do you need a check for 0 in your example?

Comment: `typeof param !== "number"`? Although I'm really not sure why you'd use a guard for this function - it's never going to be called with anything other than an index for an array. If it is, then you have a much bigger problem, since `.map` is broken. I find it highly ineffective to guard against core functionality not working as it should.

Comment: You could check for `typeof`, since numbers provide `number`, `null` is an `object` and `undefined` is `undefined`.

Comment: `typeof NaN` -> "number" What kind of falsey values do you want to check against? As said before your example is too trivial.

Comment: If you want to fail for any falsey value but `0`, then a simple `!!value || value===0` would do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lodash, you can use `isNil` function:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNil

if not, you can use `??`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: How would coalesce help here?

Comment: That is not how coalesce works. `null ?? '' : 'not'` **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'**